# Are NTP servers without monlist still dangerous?

Tags: denial-of-service, flooding, ntp

I've been studying DOS flood attacks, namely NTP and DNS floods. I know that monlist is the primary factor in launching these sorts of attacks, but I have one question. The problem is are these servers still dangerous without it it enabled? I mean if I tried to run a NTP packet flood without monlist enabled would it still cause a DOS attack or would nothing happen?

Comment: NTP servers can still be abused for DoS, just not as badly as when monlist is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the monlist is used for amplify the attach basically, so no the case of amplification attacks I don't think is a problem, however, the NTP servers could still be used for DoS attacks but not with amplification capabilities.